# How do you break a while loop with a keypress in WPF?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, while-loop, keypress

I've seen answers to the question of how to break out of a while loop with a keypress for a console app and a winforms app but not a WPF app. So, uh, how do you do it? Thanks.

Okay, let's elaborate:
Something like this doesn't work in a WPF (non-console) app. It throws a runtime error:

```
while(!Console.KeyAvailable)
{
//do work
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication34.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow:Window {
  private int _someVal = 0;
  private readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

  public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
    KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
    while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested) {
      await Task.Delay(1000); // Some Long Task
      tb.Text = (++_someVal).ToString();
    }
  }

  private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs) {
    if (keyEventArgs.Key == Key.A)
      cts.Cancel();
  }
}
```

It's just a rough demo, just take the concept. The only thing specific to WPF here is the manner of capturing the key-press. Everything else relating to breaking the while loop is the same across a console app or wpf or winforms.

Comment: I'm sorry, why is there a TextBlock in the MainWindow? Is this just to output something for demonstration purposes?

Comment: @zetar yes just like the `Task.Delay(1000)` it's just something to show the code is actually doing something

Comment: @zetar Also if you haven't looked into `CancellationTokenSource` do check it out [Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx) as normally only the `cts.Token` would be passed to the method that is your long running function and that can invoke `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` and sorts wherever needed. In this example detecting the `KeyDown` is the unique bit and not `CancellationTokenSource`. You could even switch `cts` here to a `bool` and it'd be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can create na event in the `KeyDown Event` in the `MainWindow` and get the `KeyEventArgs e` to know what key was pressed.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.A)
    {
        // set a flag to break the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this break a while loop in another method?

Comment: You can create a flag/global variable, and you can verify inside the while loop, if you press the key you change the his state and break the while loop.

Comment: I don't think this works in WPF unless you create another thread for the loop. Otherwise WPF will try to complete the loop before it responds to any KeyDown messages.